# ¿Cómo poner un mensaje alternativo al pasar puntero sobre una celda de una tabla html?

Tags: html, html-tabla

estoy intentando hacer que al pasar el puntero del mouse sobre una celda en específico de una tabla de html, se muestre un texto así como como un botón como el siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En donde al pasar el mouse se muestra el texto "Actualizar", lo mismo quiero hacer pero con una celda (td), me pregunto si habrá algun atributo de la etiqueta td que permita hacerlo. Gracias...

Comment: el atributo que puedes usar es `title="texto que aparece cuando el raton se queda quieto encima del elemento"` ... lo que ocurre es que quizas no se vea tan bonito como piensas, pero funciona

Comment: Muchas gracias amigo, era lo que estaba buscando y me funcionó. Exitos!